# Pagebreaking in longtable with math column

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking, longtable, tabularx

I'm trying to write some step-by-step math proof of a formula in my electronics notes. The idea is to have two columns (side by side), the 1st has some text explaining the math, the 2nd one has the math.

The `align` environment was using up too much space so after some searching I stumbled upon the `tabular` environment that uses `>` and `<` (lesser/greater symbols) to make the content of a column, entirely math.

However, when the page ends, the `tabular` environment doesn't naturally break and continue into the next page. I've tried `longtable` but can't notice any significant change when the page ends. Only the text seems to be getting smaller and smaller...

Can someone please suggest any other package or set of instructions to solve this problem of mine, please? I also noticed that the math in `tabular` and `longtable` is "small", like inline math instead of `displaystyle` math. Any chance to fix this?

Here's a MWE: *(I hope it works, I had to edit my document's preamble a little bit)*

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}

    \usepackage[in]{fullpage}

    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, xfrac}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}
    %\usepackage[cal=boondoxo, calscaled=.98]{mathalfa}
    %\usepackage[scr=boondoxo, scrscaled=.99]{mathalfa}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[italian]{cleveref}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \frenchspacing

\newcommand{\caE}[1]{\mathcal{E}\ped{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}l@{\hspace{1.5cm}}>{$}l<{$}}
    Densità di corrente totale (drift + diffusione) & J\ped{nx}=q \mu\, n\, \caE{x} +q D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\\
    Campo elettrico e potenziale & \caE{x}=-\diff[]{\phi}{x} \\
    relazione di Einstein & \dfrac{D}{\mu}=\dfrac{kT}{q} \\
    Sostituisco nella formula della dens. di corrente &  J_{x}=q\left[ n\,\mu _n \, \caE{x} + D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\right]=\dots\\
    & \dots=q D_n \left[ -\dfrac{q\,n}{kT} \diff[]{\phi}{x} + \diff[]{n}{x} \right]\\
    Moltiplico ambo i membri per $\exp{\left( -q\phi/kT\right)}$ & J_x\int_{0}^{x_d}\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \,dx = qD_n\left[ n\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \right]_{0}^{x_d}\\
    Condizz. al contorno per $\phi(x)$ & \phi(0)=0\: ;\:\phi(x_d)=(\phi_i - V_a)=(\phi_B - \phi_n - V_a)  \\
    Condizz. al contorno per $n(x)$ & n(0); \qquad\\
    Sostituisco per ottenere $J_n$ & \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I have to type a command to tell `longtable` to break and start again on the next page?

Comment: You can't break a table cell across pages.

Comment: You can use `>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}` but your MWE doesn't show any problem? it does not reach the end of the page so there is no page breaking but it would break at the `\\ ` if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`longtable` breaks naturally at the end of the page, as shown here where I have doubled the length of the table, and reduced the length of the page, so it goes on to page 2.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}

    \usepackage[in]{fullpage}

    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, xfrac}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{BOONDOX-cal}
    %\usepackage[cal=boondoxo, calscaled=.98]{mathalfa}
    %\usepackage[scr=boondoxo, scrscaled=.99]{mathalfa}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage[italian]{cleveref}
    \allowdisplaybreaks
\setlength\textheight{.3\textheight}
    \frenchspacing

\newcommand{\caE}[1]{\mathcal{E}\ped{#1}}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}

\begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}l@{\hspace{1.5cm}}>{$}l<{$}}
    Densità di corrente totale (drift + diffusione) & J\ped{nx}=q \mu\, n\, \caE{x} +q D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\\
    Campo elettrico e potenziale & \caE{x}=-\diff[]{\phi}{x} \\
    relazione di Einstein & \dfrac{D}{\mu}=\dfrac{kT}{q} \\
    Sostituisco nella formula della dens. di corrente &  J_{x}=q\left[ n\,\mu _n \, \caE{x} + D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\right]=\dots\\
    & \dots=q D_n \left[ -\dfrac{q\,n}{kT} \diff[]{\phi}{x} + \diff[]{n}{x} \right]\\
    Moltiplico ambo i membri per $\exp{\left( -q\phi/kT\right)}$ & J_x\int_{0}^{x_d}\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \,dx = qD_n\left[ n\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \right]_{0}^{x_d}\\
    Condizz. al contorno per $\phi(x)$ & \phi(0)=0\: ;\:\phi(x_d)=(\phi_i - V_a)=(\phi_B - \phi_n - V_a)  \\
    Condizz. al contorno per $n(x)$ & n(0); \qquad\\
    Sostituisco per ottenere $J_n$ & \\
    Densità di corrente totale (drift + diffusione) & J\ped{nx}=q \mu\, n\, \caE{x} +q D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\\
    Campo elettrico e potenziale & \caE{x}=-\diff[]{\phi}{x} \\
    relazione di Einstein & \dfrac{D}{\mu}=\dfrac{kT}{q} \\
    Sostituisco nella formula della dens. di corrente &  J_{x}=q\left[ n\,\mu _n \, \caE{x} + D_n \diff[]{n}{x}\right]=\dots\\
    & \dots=q D_n \left[ -\dfrac{q\,n}{kT} \diff[]{\phi}{x} + \diff[]{n}{x} \right]\\
    Moltiplico ambo i membri per $\exp{\left( -q\phi/kT\right)}$ & J_x\int_{0}^{x_d}\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \,dx = qD_n\left[ n\exp{\left( -\dfrac{q\phi}{kT} \right)} \right]_{0}^{x_d}\\
    Condizz. al contorno per $\phi(x)$ & \phi(0)=0\: ;\:\phi(x_d)=(\phi_i - V_a)=(\phi_B - \phi_n - V_a)  \\
    Condizz. al contorno per $n(x)$ & n(0); \qquad\\
    Sostituisco per ottenere $J_n$ & \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE works fine, mine not so much. I've just realised that it's because I put the `longtable` content *inside* the `outline` environment. I tried running `pdflatex` after placing `longtable` outside and got the result I wanted. It's a pity though, because this means I have to use `align` if I want to write multi-step math _within_ `outline`. Do you know of any other solution to writing compact step-by-step math inside the `outline` environment?

Comment: @WobblyWindows I don't know of an `outline` environment.

Comment: It's the [outlines](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/outlines/outlines.pdf) package but the environment is `outline` (without the final 's')

Comment: @WobblyWindows never heard of it but if you want to ask about _that_ feel free to open a new question.