# Long table with all Mathematics columns

Tags: longtable

I have a long table with all Mathematics content.  I have trouble with the specification. I copied the specification for the mathematics column from answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230289/pagebreaking-in-longtable-with-math-column) and repeated it thrice.

However, I get `illegal character in array arg.' error. Here is the MWE.  I am not able figure out what is the mistake here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}}

        \hline
        a&a^2\pmod{8}&a^2\pmod{4}\\
        \hline\endhead

    0 & 0&0 \\ \hline
    \iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    2\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    3\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    4\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    5\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    6\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    7\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    1 & 1&1 \\ \hline
    1 + \iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    1 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    1 + 3\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    1 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ \hline
    1 + 5\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    1 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    1 + 7\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    2 & 4&0 \\ \hline
    2 + \iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    2 + 2\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    2 + 3\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    2 + 4\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    2 + 5\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    2 + 6\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    2 + 7\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    3 & 1&1 \\ \hline
    3 + \iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    3 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    3 + 3\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    3 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ \hline
    3 + 5\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    3 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    3 + 7\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    4 & 0&0 \\ \hline
    4 + \iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    4 + 2\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    4 + 3\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    4 + 4\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    4 + 5\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    4 + 6\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    4 + 7\iota & 7&3 \\ \hline
    5 & 1&1 \\ \hline
    5 + \iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    5 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    5 + 3\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    5 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ \hline
    5 + 5\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    5 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    5 + 7\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    6 & 4&0 \\ \hline
    6 + \iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    6 + 2\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    6 + 3\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    6 + 4\iota & 4&0 \\ \hline
    6 + 5\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    6 + 6\iota & 0&0 \\ \hline
    6 + 7\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \hline
    7 & 1&1 \\ \hline
    7 + \iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    7 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    7 + 3\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    7 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ \hline
    7 + 5\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    7 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ \hline
    7 + 7\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need `\usepackage{array}`.

Comment: @Peter Grill, array package does not break pages automatically.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman - The suggestion isn't to employ the *environment* called `array` (in lieu of `longtable`). Instead, it is to load the `array` *package*.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the clarification. It worked. Thank you Peter Grill! I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- with use of the `tabularray` package
- since table is quite narrow, added is example where table is split on half and then write in parallel:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

% new:
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}  % <------
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewChildSelector{eacheight}
    {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {10}{8}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
entry=none,     % <---
label=none,     % <---
                ]{colspec ={*{3}{Q[l, wd=4em, mode=math]}},
                  row{eacheight} = {abovesep=2ex},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
    \toprule
% column headers
a           & a^2\bmod{8}   & a^2\bmod{4} \\ % "\bmod" for tigher spacing
    \midrule
% body of table
0           & 0             & 0         \\
\iota       & 7             & 3         \\
2\iota      & 4             & 0         \\
3\iota      & 7             & 3         \\
4\iota      & 0             & 0         \\
5\iota      & 7             & 3         \\
6\iota      & 4             & 0         \\
7\iota      & 7             & 3         \\ 

1           & 1             & 1         \\
1 + \iota   & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    a &1        \\
1 + 3\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
1 + 5\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
1 + 7\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\ 

2           & 4             & 0         \\
2 + \iota   & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 2\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
2 + 3\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 4\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
2 + 5\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 6\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
2 + 7\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\ 

3           & 1             & 1         \\
3 + \iota   & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
3 + 3\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
3 + 5\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
3 + 7\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\ 

4           & 0             & 0         \\
4 + \iota   & 7             & 3         \\
4 + 2\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
4 + 3\iota  & 7             & 3         \\
4 + 4\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
4 + 5\iota  & 7             & 3         \\
4 + 6\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
4 + 7\iota  & 7             & 3         \\

5           & 1             & 1         \\
5 + \iota   & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
5 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
5 + 3\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
5 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
5 + 5\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
5 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
5 + 7\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\ 

6           & 4             & 0         \\
6 + \iota   & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
6 + 2\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
6 + 3\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
6 + 4\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
6 + 5\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
6 + 6\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
6 + 7\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\ 
    
7           & 1             &1          \\
7 + \iota   & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
7 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
7 + 3\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
7 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
7 + 5\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
7 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
7 + 7\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup


\clearpage
    \begingroup
    \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[
entry=none,     % <---
label=none,     % <---
                ]{colspec ={@{} *{3}{X[l, mode=math]} @{\hskip 5em}
                                *{3}{X[l, mode=math]}
                            @{}},
                  rowsep = 1pt,
                  row{eacheight} = {abovesep=2ex},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
    \toprule
% column headers
a           & a^2\bmod{8}   & a^2\bmod{4}
    &   a           & a^2\bmod{8}   & a^2\bmod{4}   \\   
    \midrule
% body of table
0           & 0             & 0
    &   4           & 0             & 0         \\
\iota       & 7             & 3       
    &   4 + \iota   & 7             & 3         \\
2\iota      & 4             & 0       
   &   4 + 2\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
3\iota      & 7             & 3       
    &   4 + 3\iota  & 7             & 3         \\
4\iota      & 0             & 0      
    &   4 + 4\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
5\iota      & 7             & 3      
    &   4 + 5\iota  & 7             & 3         \\
6\iota      & 4             & 0     
   &   4 + 6\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
 7\iota      & 7             & 3     
    &   4 + 7\iota  & 7             & 3         \\
%
1           & 1             & 1      
    &   5           & 1             & 1         \\
1 + \iota   & 2\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   5 + \iota   & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    a &1     
    &   5 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
1 + 3\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   5 + 3\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1      
   &   5 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
1 + 5\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   5 + 5\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
1 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1      
    &   5 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
1 + 7\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   5 + 7\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\

2           & 4             & 0        
    &   6           & 4             & 0         \\
2 + \iota   & 3 + 4\iota    & 3       
    &   6 + \iota   & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 2\iota  & 0             & 0       
    &   6 + 2\iota  & 0             & 0         \\
2 + 3\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3       
    &   6 + 3\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 4\iota  & 4             & 0       
    &   6 + 4\iota  & 4             & 0         \\
2 + 5\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3      
    &   6 + 5\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 6\iota  & 0             & 0       
    &   6 + 6\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\
2 + 7\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3      
    &   6 + 7\iota  & 3 + 4\iota    & 3         \\

3           & 1             & 1       
    &   7           & 1             &1          \\
3 + \iota   & 6\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   7 + \iota   & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1      
    &   7 + 2\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
3 + 3\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota 
    &   7 + 3\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1      
    &   7 + 4\iota  & 1             & 1         \\
3 + 5\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota 
   &   7 + 5\iota  & 6\iota        & 2\iota    \\
3 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1      
    &   7 + 6\iota  & 5 + 4\iota    & 1         \\
3 + 7\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota
    &   7 + 7\iota  & 2\iota        & 2\iota    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

The first example where table occupy three pages:

[image]

and second example, where table occupy only one page:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In addition to following @PeterGrill's suggestion to load the [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package, you may want to give some thought to give the `longtable` more visual appeal. Importantly, it isn't necessary -- or even advisable -- to draw a horizontal line (via an `\hline` directive) after every single row. Instead, just omit all those lines and insert a bit of whitespace after every eighth row (via an `\addlinespace` directive, a macro provided by the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.

The following screenshot shows the first 12 rows of the resulting table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

% new:
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left-aligned, automatic math mode

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{@{} LLL @{}}
    
    % headers and footers
    \toprule
    a & a^2\bmod{8} & a^2\bmod{4} \\ % "\bmod" for tigher spacing
    \midrule
    \endhead
        
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot

    % body of table
    0      & 0&0 \\ 
    \iota  & 7&3 \\ 
    2\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    3\iota & 7&3 \\ 
    4\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    5\iota & 7&3 \\ 
    6\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    7\iota & 7&3 \\ \addlinespace
    1 & 1&1 \\ 
    1 + \iota  & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    1 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    1 + 3\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    1 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ 
    1 + 5\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    1 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    1 + 7\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \addlinespace
    2 & 4&0 \\ 
    2 + \iota  & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    2 + 2\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    2 + 3\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    2 + 4\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    2 + 5\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    2 + 6\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    2 + 7\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \addlinespace
    3 & 1&1 \\ 
    3 + \iota  & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    3 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    3 + 3\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    3 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ 
    3 + 5\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    3 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    3 + 7\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ \addlinespace
    4 & 0&0 \\ 
    4 + \iota  & 7&3 \\ 
    4 + 2\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    4 + 3\iota & 7&3 \\ 
    4 + 4\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    4 + 5\iota & 7&3 \\ 
    4 + 6\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    4 + 7\iota & 7&3 \\ \addlinespace
    5 & 1&1 \\ 
    5 + \iota  & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    5 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    5 + 3\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    5 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ 
    5 + 5\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    5 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    5 + 7\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ \addlinespace
    6 & 4&0 \\ 
    6 + \iota  & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    6 + 2\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    6 + 3\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    6 + 4\iota & 4&0 \\ 
    6 + 5\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ 
    6 + 6\iota & 0&0 \\ 
    6 + 7\iota & 3 + 4\iota&3 \\ \addlinespace
    7 & 1&1 \\ 
    7 + \iota  & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    7 + 2\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    7 + 3\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    7 + 4\iota & 1&1 \\ 
    7 + 5\iota & 6\iota&2\iota \\ 
    7 + 6\iota & 5 + 4\iota&1 \\ 
    7 + 7\iota & 2\iota&2\iota \\ 
    \end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

May I offer one improvement for the table? I personally dislike the left alignment of each column. I would suggest to centre columns w.r.t the headers, however make the content of each cell left or right aligned with respect to other cells. This however adds a little more code but visually improves the table presentation.

The code below creates inner boxes in cells via `\eqmakebox` ([eqparbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package). The advantage is boxes share the same width in the same column making cells as wide as the longest expression. The boxes are centred w.r.t. to headers but their content can still be left-, middle- or right-aligned--see the line with `\eqmakebox[col1][l]{...}` where `l` determines the inner left alignment. In order to format cells this way, I utilise macros in cells via `\collectcell...\endcollectcell` ([collcell](https://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) package).

I also defined a custom operator `\opmod` because `\pmod` seems to create too much extra space, which uis not ideal for a header.

Here's the full code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{booktabs}   % improved rules
\usepackage{eqparbox}   % boxes in cells with inner alignments
\usepackage{collcell}   % run macros inside cells

\NewDocumentCommand\opmod{sm}{%
  \ensuremath{\IfBooleanF{#1}{\;}(\operatorname{mod}#2)}}

% The following block requires two packages: eqparbox and collcell
\newcommand\colleft[1]{\eqmakebox[col1][l]{$#1$}}
\newcommand\colmid[1]{\eqmakebox[col2][r]{$#1$}}
\newcommand\colright[1]{\eqmakebox[col3][r]{$#1$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\colleft}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\colmid}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\colright}c<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{L @{\hspace{12pt}} M R}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{$a$}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a^2\opmod{4}$}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a^2\opmod{8}$} \\
  \midrule\endhead
  \bottomrule\endfoot
  0           &  0           & 0 \\
  \iota       &  7           & 3 \\
  2\iota      &  4           & 0 \\
  3\iota      &  7           & 3 \\
  4\iota      &  0           & 0 \\
  5\iota      &  7           & 3 \\
  6\iota      &  4           & 0 \\
  7\iota      &  7           & 3 \\
  1           &  1           & 1 \\
  1 + \iota   &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  1 + 2\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  1 + 3\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  1 + 4\iota  &  1           & 1 \\
  1 + 5\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  1 + 6\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  1 + 7\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  2           &  4           & 0 \\
  2 + \iota   &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  2 + 2\iota  &  0           & 0 \\
  2 + 3\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  2 + 4\iota  &  4           & 0 \\
  2 + 5\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  2 + 6\iota  &  0           & 0 \\
  2 + 7\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  3           &  1           & 1 \\
  3 + \iota   &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  3 + 2\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  3 + 3\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  3 + 4\iota  &  1           & 1 \\
  3 + 5\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  3 + 6\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  3 + 7\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  4           &  0           & 0 \\
  4 + \iota   &  7           & 3 \\
  4 + 2\iota  &  4           & 0 \\
  4 + 3\iota  &  7           & 3 \\
  4 + 4\iota  &  0           & 0 \\
  4 + 5\iota  &  7           & 3 \\
  4 + 6\iota  &  4           & 0 \\
  4 + 7\iota  &  7           & 3 \\
  5           &  1           & 1 \\
  5 + \iota   &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  5 + 2\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  5 + 3\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  5 + 4\iota  &  1           & 1 \\
  5 + 5\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  5 + 6\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  5 + 7\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  6           &  4           & 0 \\
  6 + \iota   &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  6 + 2\iota  &  0           & 0 \\
  6 + 3\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  6 + 4\iota  &  4           & 0 \\
  6 + 5\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  6 + 6\iota  &  0           & 0 \\
  6 + 7\iota  &  3 + 4\iota  & 3 \\
  7           &  1           & 1 \\
  7 + \iota   &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  7 + 2\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  7 + 3\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
  7 + 4\iota  &  1           & 1 \\
  7 + 5\iota  &  6\iota      & 2\iota \\
  7 + 6\iota  &  5 + 4\iota  & 1 \\
  7 + 7\iota  &  2\iota      & 2\iota \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

and a screen shot

[image]